# GAPI missing couple number in visitors

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using GAPI library and I'm having problems retreiving the unique visits from general information of my site.
(not pageviews or anything)

For visits I'm using:

```
$ga->requestReportData(ga_profile_id,array('userDefinedValue'),array('visits'), $sort_metric=null, $filter=null, $start_date,$end_date,$start_index=1,$max_results=100);

echo $ga->getVisits();
```

And work perfect, giving me the exact number.

And for the unique visits:

```
$ga->requestReportData(ga_profile_id,array('userDefinedValue'),array('visitors'), $sort_metric=null, $filter=null, $start_date,$end_date,$start_index=1,$max_results=100);

echo $ga->getVisitors(); //gives me 771.047
```

Which gives me ALMOST the same number, which should be 797.731.

Not sure what im doing wrong, hope you can help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i found the solution,

for the **dimension** I have to use "**day**" instead of "**userDefinedValue**

```
    $ga->requestReportData(ga_profile_id,array('day'),array('visitors'), $sort_metric=null, $filter=null, $start_date,$end_date,$start_index=1,$max_results=100);

echo $ga->getVisitors(); //gives me the correct answer
```